# Function to sum all permutations

Tags: c, recursion, permutation

some time ago I wrote a program that prints all possible permutations of  of a given array, even printing all partial arrays:

```
    #define MAXARRAY 32
    #include <stdio.h>
    void combinations(int array[], int temp[], int start, int end,  int index, int r);

    void print_combinations(int array[], int n, int r){
    int temp[r];
    combinations(array, temp, 0, n-1, 0, r);
    }

    void combinations(int array[], int temp[], int start, int end, int index, int r){
    if (index == r){
        for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
            printf("%d ", temp[j]);
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++){
        temp[index] = array[i];
        combinations(array, temp, i+1, end, index+1, r);
    }
}

int main(){
    int array[MAXARRAY];
    int r;
    int n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    int i=MAXarray, j;
    for(j=0;j<MAXARRAY;j++){
        array[j]=j+1;
    }
    for(r=0;r<=i;r++)
    print_combinations(array, n, r);    
}
```

Now I'm trying to convert this program to do the following:

Instead of printing the permutations, I want to sum up ALL permutations and compare the sum with a fixed value, and if the sum of numbers in the permutation truly is equal to that fixed value, it increases the counter so in the end I could check how many sums of permutation equals that value. This is what I came up with for now:

```
#define MAXARRAY 32
#include <stdio.h>
int combinations (int array[], int temp[], int start, int end,  int index, int r);

void print_combinations (int array[], int n, int r){
    int temp[r];
    combinations(array, temp, 0, n-1, 0, r);
}

int combinations (int array[], int temp[], int start, int end, int index, int r){
    int sum=0, counter=0;
    if (index == r) {
        for (int j=0; j<r; j++){
            sum=sum+temp[j];
            }
        if(sum==264){
        counter++;
        }
    }
    for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++){
        temp[index] = array[i];
        combinations(array, temp, i+1, end, index+1, r);
    }
    return counter;
}


int main()
{
    int array[MAXARRAY];
    int r;
    int n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    int i=MAXARRAY, j;
    for(j=0;j<MAXARRAY;j++){
        array[j]=j+1;
    }
    for(r=0;r<=i;r++)
    print_combinations(array, n, r);
```

I don't know how to alter this correctly to get what I want, precisely I am a bit lost with how to switch up the void function to print a counter that does not appear in the function, and I am unsure if I can just easily "alter" this code to get what I want, or I just need to write completely new functions.

Comment: I dont understand, if you wrote code that calculated all permutations you don't need to convert anything. Just calculate the sum for each permutation?

Comment: To clarify, first code PRINTS all permutations.
I need the second code to CALCULATE sums of all previously printed permutations.

Comment: Give an example on the second one...

Comment: please give more info about input data and limits, this may seem non recurive task that works for N , not N!

Comment: input is the series of numbers from 1 to 32,(1,2,3,4...31,32) and there are no limits, it doesn't need to be efficient at all, i just need an one-time answer. It won't be ran in any larger programs (for now).

Comment: @JakovSergo so what do you consider as a sum of permutation ? for input 1 2 3, it is 123 + 132 + 213 + 231 + 312 + 321 ? right ?

Comment: @JakovSergo and as u understand , there are n! permudations for a N-length sequence. so 32! is ~~ 2.6*10^35 , recursive solution will work longer than your age is, + parials,

Comment: What you print and try to sum aren't permutations, where the order of a fixed set of things matters; they are combinations, where whether an item is in the set or not matters. Summation is commutative, so order doesn't matter. This will boil down the possibilities to 2 ³² (~4 billion) from 32! (~2.6e35).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to know in how many ways you can pick numbers from a given set so that they sum up to a given target value. You seem to approach this the wrong way, because you have mixed up permutations and combinations.

[Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) are different arrangements of a set of items with a fixed size `n` and number of possible arrangements is `n!` if all of the items are different. That's of no use here, because summation is commutative; the order of operands doesn't matter.

[Combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) tell you which items of a set are included and which are not. This is what you want here. Luckily for you, there are only 2ⁿ possilbe ways to pick items from a set of *n*, including all items or none.

You can also solve this recursively. Each level of recursion treats one item and you can either chose to include it or not. For thee items, you get the following decision tree:

```
                                  0
                                /   \
                              0       1
                             / \     / \
                            0   2   0   2
                           / \ / \ / \ / \
                           0 3 0 3 0 3 0 3

                 sum       0 3 2 5 1 4 3 6
```

Take the left branch to omit an item and take the right branch to include it. This will give you the sum of 3 twice and all other sums from 0 to 6 inclusively once. There are 8 possible paths.

The program below does that:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 32
#define TARGET 264

/*
 *      Print the summands
 */
void print(const int a[], int n)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i) printf(" + ");
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }

    puts("");
}

/*
 *      Actual recursive combination function
 */
size_t combine_r(const int pool[],      // summand pool
                 int res[],             // currently included items
                 int max,               // length of pool
                 int n,                 // length of res
                 int i,                 // current item's index in pool
                 int sum,               // running sum
                 int target)            // desired target
{
    int count = 0;

    if (i == max) {
        if (sum == target) {
            //print(res, n);
            count++;
        }
    } else {
        count += combine_r(pool, res, max, n, i + 1, sum, target);

        res[n++] = pool[i];
        count += combine_r(pool, res, max, n, i + 1,
            sum + pool[i], target);
    }

    return count;
}

/*
 *      Interface function for the recursive function.
 */
size_t combine(const int pool[], int n, int target)
{
    int res[n];

    return combine_r(pool, res, n, 0, 0, 0, target);
}



int main()
{
    int pool[N];
    size_t n;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) pool[i] = i + 1;

    n = combine(pool, N, TARGET);
    printf("%zu combinations.\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

The function goes down each path and records a hit if the sum equals the target. The number of hits in each subtree is returned as you return from the recursion and go up the tree, so that the root level you've got the total number of hits.

The function `combine` is just a front-end to the actual recursive function, so that you don't have to pass so many zeros from `main`. The arguments for the recursive function could probably be reduced and organised more elegantly. (Tow of them exist only because in C you have to pass i the length of an array. If you just want to count the possibilities, you can get rid of `res` and `n`, which just serve to print the array.)